# Key_Value count filters Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dataset, frequency, word-frequency

I am trying to write a filter where I am trying to find key and value frequency counts. While trying in one of the code blocks I face the below error difficulty.

The data is about twitter user and the respective keywords. I am trying to get the frequency of user's tweet count and every unique keyword's count posted by the respective user. The data-set has about 1000s of rows and only 20 of those I have shown in Input.

Input

```
tweetcricscore  7.15E+17    3/30/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.15E+17    3/30/2016   #sausvsvic
tweetcricscore  7.15E+17    3/30/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.15E+17    3/30/2016   #sausvsvic
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/28/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/28/2016   #sausvsvic
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/27/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/27/2016   #sausvsvic
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/27/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/27/2016   #sausvsvic
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/26/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/26/2016   #canvsnk
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/26/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/26/2016   #sausvsvic
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/26/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/26/2016   #sausvsvic
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/26/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.14E+17    3/26/2016   #sausvsvic
tweetcricscore  7.13E+17    3/23/2016   #wt20
tweetcricscore  7.13E+17    3/23/2016   #indvsban
```

Code:

```
with open('filter_1.csv', 'rb') as inp,open('filter_2.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    '''for row in csv.reader(inp):
        l.append(row[0])'''
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        try:
            key_val = row[0],row[3]
            d[key_val] +=1
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

    for key,values in od.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([key[0],l.count(key[0]),key[3],values])
```

Expected Output

```
tweetcricscore  234 #afgvssco   51
tweetcricscore  234 #afgvszim   46
tweetcricscore  234 #banvsire   12
tweetcricscore  234 #banvsned   46
tweetcricscore  234 #canvsnk    1
tweetcricscore  234 #cricket    178
tweetcricscore  234 #engvswi    46
tweetcricscore  234 #hkvssco    23
tweetcricscore  234 #indvsban   1
tweetcricscore  234 #sausvsvic  8
tweetcricscore  234 #wt20   56
```

I am getting following error

```
28 
     29         for key,values in od.iteritems():
---> 30                 writer.writerow([key[0],l.count(key[0]),key[3],values])
     32 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The code is just part of a process program and this part is showing me error in filtering the input. 
Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `key_val = row[0],row[3]` is a tuple containing 2 items; but `writer.writerow([key[0],l.count(key[0]),key[3],values])` refers to the 4th item. Hence error occurs.

Comment: @ccf I could use some help with this one http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11440/multi-model-data-set-visualization-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't run the example you provided but based on reading the code it seems that you're generating a `dict` where keys are tuples that each have two elements:

```
key_val = row[0],row[3]
d[key_val] +=1
```

Then you generate `OrderedDict` where you are using same keys and iterate over the items on it:

```
for key,values in od.iteritems():
    writer.writerow([key[0],l.count(key[0]),key[3],values])
```

On second line you try to get element at index 3 from `key` which naturally fails because it only has two elements in it. If you change `key[3]` to `key[1]` instead it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you ..  :) This absolutely worked but faced problems in next block of code :(

Comment: I could use some help with this one too http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11440/multi-model-data-set-visualization-python